# "no activity found to handle intent" Not all phones have Android Market installed

Tags: android, android-intent

Not all phones have Android Market installed, and therefore using intent to open market app fails.

What's the best way to handle this?

- Hide this feature if user doesn't have Android Market installed (how would I detect this?).
- Handle the possible error, how (and possibly suggest that the user downloads the Android Market)?

Comment: The user cannot download the Android Market.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the answer above is that if you just pass a URL the user will be prompted how to handle the Intent.

A more graceful way to do it IMO, expanding upon the [1st answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370433/1851478), is to test whether the market app is installed, and then if not, pass a URL (which actually you would then want to test to see if something can handle that intent, but if you happen to have a device without both the play store and a browser then I would question why the user would have my app installed in the first place (another story I suppose)....

Perhaps there is a better way, but here's what works for me:

```
private String getMarketURI(String marketURL) {
    String returnURL = "";
    PackageManager packageManager = getApplication().getPackageManager();
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://" + marketURL);
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
    if (marketIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        returnURL = "market://" + marketURL;
    } else {
        returnURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/" + marketURL;
    }
    return returnURL;
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse(getMarketURI("details?id=com.yourapps.packagename")));
```

Answer (score 3):

If your app is being provided by Android Market, then it does have Android Market installed. :)

Okay that is snide, but there is an important truth -- Google goes to a lot of effort to enforce compatibility guarantees on devices for them to be allowed to ship with Android Market, so that is how you can know that whatever you are running on will behave as it should.

If you are delivering your app from something besides Android Market, you need to get information from whoever is delivering the app about what compatibility guarantees they have.

If they don't have compatibility guarantees (or you are just putting a raw .apk up on a web site or such), then you have a complete crap shoot.  The device you are running on could have had its software modified in pretty much any way, and have any kind of differences in behavior you can imagine.

That said, if you want to determine whether there is an activity on the current device to handle a particular Intent, you can use this: [PackageManager.resolveActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use the web address as the intent target and then if there is no android market it will open in a browser.