# how to Rate my App in OnBackPresssed methode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialog

I'm trying to rate my app in onBackPressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(ChooseMenu.this)
        .setMessage("Rate My Application")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Rate it",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int id) {
                        mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        finish();
                    }
                }).show();
```

LogCat :

```
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.moblication5.india.homeeelectriccalculator }
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.moblication5.india.homeeelectriccalculator.ChooseMenu$6.onClick(ChooseMenu.java:167)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-23 23:22:09.476: E/AndroidRuntime(594):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: while clicking the rate button application was stopping unexpectedly @Geralt

Comment: I guess.... mcontext is null? Just a guess. Post the stacktrace and we can help better.

Comment: Add here your logcat.

Comment: ya updated Logcat @Geralt

Comment: @KlynCrishnan what contains your `APP_PNAME` variable exactly? Add here its content.

Comment: similar to [this problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073832/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent

running your code on emulator?

Comment: its a package name declared globally private final static String APP_PNAME = "com.klyncrishnan.xxxxxxxxxxx"; @Geralt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
```

to

```
mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
```

Not all phones have Google Play installed and know what to do with `market://` urls.

Some other solutions here:
["no activity found to handle intent" Not all phones have Android Market installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370193/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-not-all-phones-have-android-market-installe)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you missed initializing context

do this in `onCreate`

```
mcontext = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `mcontext` publicly, and initialize it in `onCreate`. For example:

```
public Context mcontext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mcontext = this;
}
```

And then change this:

```
mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                       Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PNAME)));
```

To this:

```
mcontext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
          Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + APP_NAME)));
```

where `APP_NAME` is your app's **package name**.